# Don't forget to check for duplicates, please!

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This is just a friendly reminder to please help our site out by looking for duplicate questions. This site is really busy at the moment, which is a great thing. However one down side of that is that there have been many times recently when I've seen a new question that has a quite obvious duplicate older question, but by the time I see the question and close it as a duplicate it already has received several answers. This is unfortunate because it splits the answers into two places, and any answers on the closed question probably won't be seen as much as the original question.

But of course it's not the moderators' sole responsibility to close questions. If we can all do a little bit of duplicate hunting, then we'll spread the work out.

Please consider doing the following when you see a question that interests you:

1. Check the existing comments for anyone suggesting a duplicate target. If you agree, then consider voting/flagging it, and please don't write an answer, but do go visit the older question!
2. Please edit questions so that they always have the relevant tags for the books they ask about, as well as any major themes, characters, or doctrines. Accurate tags are useful for the Related questions column.
3. Take a quick look at the Related questions column. Often duplicate questions will be shown there.
4. Consider making a quick 30 second check for any duplicate questions. If you've been on this site for a while you'll probably start getting a feel for what sort of questions have been asked before. After almost 10 years and over 10,000 questions, a lot of the common questions about the Bible have been asked already. Questions that are less technical and don't concern particularly obscure topics are most likely to have been asked before. So it would really help if you make a quick search for related questions. But don't worry if you can't find anything. The search engine here is far from perfect, and it can't interpret synonyms like a human can. Don't feel bad if you look for duplicates, can't find anything, and then someone else does. We're all on the same team, so it doesn't matter when we miss one.

If we can find more of these duplicate questions, then it will mean all the answers will be on the same page. This will mean we'll be able to better compare competing interpretations, and we'll avoid duplicating the work of others before us. Thank you everyone for your work on maintaining this site!

Comment: This is a really important point and something that's been happening a lot recently, so thanks for bringing this up! It's easy to get caught in that trap of writing an Answer for a question that is a duplicate, or is otherwise off-topic. The more contributors we have checking and flagging questions for closure, the better an experience the site will be for all users, old and new. :)

Comment: Noted and understood  . . . .  will do.